# Modelling external JS objects

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

PixiJS (or rather, [Resource Loader](https://github.com/englercj/resource-loader)), returns a JS object shaped like this in the callback of the load function:

```
{
    "resource-you-asked-for.png": {
        url: "foo.png",
        error: <optional error>,
        data: <binary data>
    },
    "second-resource.png": { ... }
}
```

My question is...how do I model this in Kotlin.js? I can't just say this is a `Map<String, LoaderResult>` -- then Kotlin will try to use `get` (a mangled `get` actually) to index into it. And I can't subclass `dynamic` obviously.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript object that acts like a Map can be used in Kotlin as [external interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html#external-interfaces) with extension `get` and `set` operator functions:

```
external interface ResourceDictionary

inline operator fun ResourceDictionary.get(name: String): LoaderResult? =
    this.asDynamic()[name]

inline operator fun ResourceDictionary.set(name: String, result: LoaderResult?) {
    this.asDynamic()[name] = result
}
```

---

JavaScript object that acts like a class be used in Kotlin as [external class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html#external-modifier)

```
external open class LoaderResult {
   var url: String
   var data: ByteArray
   var error: Error?
}
```

---

You can also convert TypeScript definitions using [ts2kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt) tool:

1. `$ npm install -g ts2kt`
2. Find [index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pixi.js/index.d.ts) file for PixiJS
3. `$ ts2kt index.d.ts`

Then you'll be able to find `external interface ResourceDictionary` and `external open class Resource` in `pixi.PIXI.loaders.kt`: